# Lists and Adapters

Tags: java, android

How can I log the user's vote for their favorite game from the array in mGames?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.ListView;

public class GameListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public String[] mGames = {
        "Age of Empires",
        "Civilization",
        "Minecraft",
        "SimCity"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mGames);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.d("List Item: ", "Clicked!");
    }


    public void sendVote(String game) {
        VoteService.recordVote(game);
    }
}
```

The helper method...sendVote(), will log the user's vote
    for their favorite game...How can i call the correct game from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as Malik wrote, and then put

```
sendVote(mGames[position]);
```

inside *onListItemClick(...)*

Comment: Yeah, I put a Log statement in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the item listener:

```
public class GameListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener
```

And set listener in the `onCreate` method:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list);
list.setListAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnClickListener(this);
```